# Workaround for String.Contains() in C# .NetCF 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, .net-2.0

There is a string method called Contains. It allows you to quickly search a string for another string. I need to use this in a .netcf 2.0 application but per MSDN it does not come available until the 3.5 framework.

Can anyone offer a work around (C#)?

TIA
Noble

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try using [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx). If it returns -1, the string does not exist inside the other string.

Answer (score 2):

What about `string.IndexOf` and just check to see if it returns greater than -1?

Answer (score 1):

Browsing "**String.Contains**" in Reflector gives below. I think this can be used  directly in code.

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    Return (Me.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
End Function
```

Also a C# version

```
public bool Contains(string value)
{
    return (this.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0);
}
```